# Using Empty String as SecretKeySpec

Tags: android, cryptography, aes

so my question i straight forward
can someone use an Empty String as SecretKeySpec with AES

```
String a = "";
Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(a.getBytes("UTF8"), "AES");
```

and then use it to encrypt Strings

```
String str = "String that needs encoding";
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF8");
Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
instance.init(1, secretKeySpec);
byte[] b = new byte[instance.getBlockSize()];
instance.doFinal(b, instance.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length, b, 0));
String str2 = new String(Base64.encode(b));
```

This is just a snippet from the whole code

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

No this will not work, because the key size of AES is fixed to 16 byte (128 bit), 24 byte (192 bit) or 32 byte (256 bit).

And empty SecretKeySpec would mean you are using a key of length 0. I assume that this will end up in the following Exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty key`

BTW: Your code is strange as it encrypts the data partially twice:

`instance.doFinal(b, instance.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length, b, 0));`

First `instance.update` encrypts the content from `bytes` to `b`. Then `instance.doFinal` encrypts the content of `b` a second time.

Comment: you are right.i just needed a second opinion on this that is more qualified then me.this code was provided to me written by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

No string should ever be directly used as a key, so the question to me makes no sense. If you want to generate a key from a passphrase you should use a password hash such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2.

A symmetric key consists of an number of bits, usually bytes or octets. These bytes should be completely random to an adversary. If they are not then you will not achieve the security that a symmetric cipher promises.

You could store the key as hexadecimals or base 64. This is however not recommended as strings are generally kept forever in memory for many managed languages such as Java. If a key (initially) consists of bytes then those bytes should be cleared as soon as they are no longer needed.

Note that ECB is not a secure mode of operation for 95% of cases where a cipher is required. Instead use a secure mode of operation such as GCM and prefix a unique or secure random (12 byte) IV to the ciphertext.

---

It depends on the cryptographic function which kind of keys are accepted by the implementation, even if they do not make sense (you'd expect at least 128 bits of randomness, after all). For instance HMAC authentication - not a cipher - accepts a key of any size. The Java implementation seems however to require at least one byte for `SecretKeySpec`.

---

All in all, I guess the empty string was just left there for you to fill in.